# Extract CSV columns without quotes

Tags: bash, command-line, terminal, zsh, csvfix

`csvfix order -f 1 my.csv` outputs

```
"Name"
"1"
"2"
"3"
```

How can I output

```
Name
1
2
3
```

Instead?

Comment: pipe it to `sed`?  `.... | sed 's/"//g'`

Comment: @Jetchisel that will break a field with escaped quotes

Comment: `csvfix order -f 1 my.csv | sed 's/"//g'` that breaks the escaped quotes?

Comment: @Jetchisel of course `"he said ""who are you?"""` will become `he said who are you?` instead of `he said "who are you?"`